# Yahoo: forward all emails to another email address, and delete them

Tags: email, yahoo-mail, email-forwarding

I'd like to forward all emails incoming to my Yahoo email.

[This method](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/new-mail-for-desktop/sln29133.html) works:

> Click Settings Image of the Settings icon..
>   Click More Settings.
>   Click Mailboxes.
>   Click the primary mailbox account.
>   Under Forwarding, enter the Forwarding Address.
>   Click Verify.
>   Log in to your forwarding address and follow the instructions sent there.

But then, **all these forwarded emails still stay in the Yahoo inbox**.

How to enable "forward + delete the original in the Yahoo inbox" automatically?

I thought about doing a "Filter", but how? and are we sure that a "Delete" filter would be applied **after** it is forwarded? (and not before!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "Delete" filter works exactly as it should.

I set up email forwarding to another email account and then set up a "Delete" filter. Any email containing "@" in the "From" field (which is basically all emails) are moved to "Trash". I tested it and it appears to work as intended. Emails show up at the forwarded address and are no longer sitting in my yahoo inbox.